# Convert sql into search for rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I have two models which i want to search through my Search form

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'search'}, {:method => 'get', :remote => true })  do |select| %>
<%= label_tag :search, "Enter Keywords Here" %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>

<%= label_tag :country, "Search by Country" %>
<%= collection_select(:country, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please Select') %>

<%= label_tag :difficulty, "Search by Difficulty" %>
<%= select_tag :difficulty, options_for_select([['Beginner'],['Intermediate'],['Expert']]), {:prompt => 'Please Select'} %>

<%= label_tag :preperation_time, "Search by preperation time" %>
<%= select_tag :preperation_time, options_for_select([['15..30'],['30..60'],['60..120']]), {:prompt => 'Please Select'} %><br>

<%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "searchbutton" %>
<% end %>
```

My understanding is that if I want to be able to search on all the columns my sql statement should look like this

```
SELECT column dish_name, difficulty, preparation_time FROM Recipe LEFT JOIN Country ON Recipe.dish_name = Country.name AND Recipe.difficulty = Country.name AND Recipe.preparation_time = Country.name
```

this may be totally wrong mind, what i would like to achieve is to be able to search by one parameter or up to all 4

Im not sure how to turn this into rails syntax, currently I have

```
q = "%#{params[:search]}%"
@countrysearch = Recipe.includes(:country).where("dish_name LIKE ? OR countries.name LIKE ? OR difficulty LIKE ? OR preperation_time LIKE?", q, q, q,q )
```

If anyone can point me on the right direction that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Undestanding**

If you want to understand better what you are doing with this methods call, you can always use the `to_sql` in order to print the generated SQL Query.

Also you can check in the log degenrated by rails and in the console.

**Left Join Example**

```
@result = Recipe.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON countries.id = recipes.country_id").select
```

but is also possible, and better to do how you are doing

```
@result = Recipe.includes(:country)
```

**Printing the query**

```
puts @result.to_sql
```

**Building the query**

```
countrysearch = Recipe.includes(:country).arel_table
countrysearch = countrysearch.or(countrysearch[:country].eq(params[:search][:country])) if params[:search].has_key?(:country)
#...
countrysearch = countrysearch.or(countrysearch[:difficulty].eq(params[:search][:difficulty])) if params[:search].has_key?(:difficulty)
```

**References**

Please check for the alternatives in the following references:

1. [rails/arel](https://github.com/rails/arel)
2. [215: Advanced Queries in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3)

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: thank you very much, will study the references you have suggested

Comment: Have you tried the approach I mentioned in your solution, does it worked?

Comment: apologies for delay, well i have tried building as suggested using arel.table but for some reason i get an internal server error 500. still trying to read the resources and understand them

Comment: Hopw you are supposed to get server error 500 building a query? This does not makes any sense. Anyways, try to do it in the console, before adapting it to your controller. To run the console use "rails c"